# How-to: Does azure service fabric statefull services, reliable-collections replace SQL-azure?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

As an Azure service fabric newbie I have a question concerning '**reliable collections**'.

If 've read the documentation and I'm starting to wonder how reliable collections be used ?
- Do they replace DB systems?
- Do they only support x-process|node state sharing scenarios?
- Should they only be used as an optimized cache? 
 
- What would be the typical size of a reliable collection: MB/0-5GB/5-10GB?

Comment: What do you mean with *Do they only support x-process|node state sharing scenarios?*

Answer (score 4):

**Do they replace DB systems?**

Not necessarily, it is like comparing apples and oranges. First of all, there are multiple types of DB engines, like relational engines (SQL Server) and NoSQL engines (like CosmosDB). Typically databases can be queried from the outside whilst the typical scenario for reliable collections is to host only that data that the service needs for its own state.

For example, a real database can be used by several Service Fabric Services. A reliable collection is meant to be used by one service.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections):

> The key difference between Reliable Collections and other high-availability technologies (such as Redis, Azure Table service, and Azure Queue service) is that the state is kept locally in the service instance while also being made highly available.

External database engines still have their place, for example for reporting purposes.

**Should they only be used as an optimized cache**

No, there are better caching products that can offer better functionality, for example there is no baked in support for automatic cache invalidation in reliable collections.

Service Fabric is a really great platform for building microservices. In the microservice philosophy the concept to use a data store per microservice takes a prominent place. In order to reduce latency for data retrieval reliable collections can be used. It is also outlined in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-scenarios)

**What would be the typical size of a reliable collection: MB/0-5GB/5-10GB?**

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-common-questions#how-much-data-can-i-store-in-a-reliable-collection):

> Reliable services are typically partitioned, so the amount you can store is only limited by the number of machines you have in the cluster, and the amount of memory available on those machines.
>
> As an example, suppose that you have a reliable collection in a service with 100 partitions and 3 replicas, storing objects that average 1 kb in size. Now suppose that you have a 10 machine cluster with 16gb of memory per machine. For simplicity and to be conservative, assume that the operating system and system services, the Service Fabric runtime, and your services consume 6gb of that, leaving 10gb available per machine, or 100 gb for the cluster.

Comment: Is there any other tool like reliable collections that can keep the state locally?